# Why I need to press back button twice to dismiss fragment on first time?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-navigationview, appcompatactivity

I have `Base Activity` including `NavigationView` with 2 `menu items`. On start it loads `Home fragment` having `background image` inside it. Each loads specific `fragment`. When I select Terms & Conditions menu item, it loads T&C `fragment` & when I press back button it simply kills it.

However, when I select About Us menu item, it loads About Us `fragment` but I need to press `BACK button` twice to kill it. I need to know why does it happen?

Part of Code in `AppBaseActivity`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.body_container, homeFragment, "");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        navigationView.getMenu().findItem(item.getItemId()).setChecked(true);
switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_terms :
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                TCFragment tcFragment = new TCFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.body_container, tcFragment, "");
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_about_us :
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                AboutUsFragment aboutUsFragment = new AboutUsFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.body_container, aboutUsFragment, "");
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                break;
}

DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
}
```

`All fragments` simply have overridden `onCreateView()` by inflating respected xml only. No code is written in both `fragments` yet.

Comment: use .add instead of .replace  for loading fragment and see

Comment: did you override `onBackPressed()`

Comment: But why it works in case of T&C fragment then?

Comment: @kishorejethava No I didn't.

Comment: May be because you are adding Home fragment. Try with replace there.

Comment: @kishorejethava Nothing happened. Issue is still alive

Comment: Is your drawer layout would be in open state while switch fragment. means are you closing drawer after completing replace fragment?

Comment: Yes. I close it, on selecting any drawer item.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop back hardware navigation if you want.

Simply using `onBackPressed()` without `super.onBackPressed()`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();    
}
```

Comment: A brief explanation could be useful for OP.